# Is it possible to recover Windows 7's Shadow Files from different computer?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, system-restore

Is VSC recoverable from HD using different computer?

When I re-installed Windows 7, I realized that I did not backup some of my important files. I recovered  gigs of data including system restore files. Some of the files are corrupted. I was wondering if it is possible to open VSC (Volume Shadow Copy) files on different computer?

Comment: It actually stands for _Volume_ Shadow Copy.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped it.

Answer (score 2):

[Shadow Explorer](http://www.shadowexplorer.com/) is a handy tool to browse what is there.  It would probably work if you mounted the drive inside another computer as a secondary drive.